# GuardedBy and concurrentHashMap

Tags: java

I saw a code snippets like below:

`@GuardedBy("this") private final Map<Id, Supplier<List<Predicate>>> filters = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();`

My question is like since this object (`filters`) is already being guarded, could I just use `HashMap` instead of `ConcurrentHashMap`?

Thank you.

Comment: "Guarded" is very abstract.  How is it being guarded where it's used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@GuardedBy("this")` is, as far as I recall, a custom annotation, which usage was advised in Java Concurrency in Practice by Brian Goetz (highly recommend reading theh book!), or possibly [this annotation](https://jcip.net/annotations/doc/net/jcip/annotations/GuardedBy.html) and it's not a standard JDK annotation. Thus, it can be only treated as a hint to the programmer, what is the lock object which guards the field which can be accessed from multiple thread, or to put it another way a marker annotation.

TL;DR - no, you cannot. If you want the access to the filters to be thread safe, leave the ConcurrentHashMap. The @GuardedBy annotation does not makes the access to the field synchronized, it just helps you understand the code.

Comment: Most likely candidate is probably this, actually https://aalmiray.github.io/jsr-305/apidocs/javax/annotation/concurrent/GuardedBy.html

Comment: I would also say that GuardedBy does not make sense in this context. `GuardedBy("this")` implies the map is guarded by additional synchronization, on top of the internal locking it does over buckets. Presumably it is not, because that would defeat the purpose of using a thread-safe collection. I would say it only really makes sense to mark things as guarded which are not already inherently thread-safe.